# How do I generate a pdf-file from a binary file

Tags: php, pdf

The binary data is simply the actual file, or rather the important contents of that file, just without file name.

```
$base64 = /* some base64 encoded data fetched from somewhere */;
$binary = base64_decode($base64);
```

And there you have the file data/contents of the file in the $binary variable. From here, it depends on what you want to do. You can write the data to a file, and you get an "actual" PDF file:

```
file_put_contents('my.pdf', $binary);
```

You can spit the data out to the browser with an appropriate header, and the user will receive something that looks like a PDF file to him:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my.pdf"');
echo $binary;
```

it generates a pdf file but it not opening..it show error occur.
     //below is the php file

```
 <?php
 $base64 = "/here binary code/";
 $binary = base64_decode($base64);
 file_put_contents('my.pdf',$binary);
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my.pdf"');
 echo $binary;
 ?>
```

then how to compare downloaded file with original file.

Comment: So is this in PHP? Something else? Have you compared the file you save with the original file, in length, hash etc?

Comment: So please put that in the question tags... and then add the other information I requested, about how the saved file compares with the original.

Comment: your saying,ask the question in question tag with your information

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm saying you should edit your question to include the php tag, and also to include information about how the downloaded file compares with the original.

Comment: i dont know how to compare the files and binary code is in database code

Comment: Well presumably the PDF came from *somewhere* to start with. If you don't have the original PDF, how do you know that the problem isn't just bad data in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't have proper data in $base64 variable. You're simply making PDF response, but content of that response is not PDF file.

(You can try to read content from some real PDF, fill this data to $binary, and it should work.)

Comment: Are you 100% sure, that in the variable that you're using is valid PDF data? I mean, if you want to generate PDF in PHP, then you should use something like [mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) or [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

Comment: hai i am fetching the binary code from database table and using that binary code to generate pdf file.

Comment: I understand, you fetch base64 encoded binary data from DB, then you base64 decode it and then you want to echo it as PDF content. But are you 100% sure, that DB field you are using as binary code is a **valid** PDF content? I dont have your data, but my first step would be to read some pdf file to variable, and use this variable instead of $binary to check where is the problem.

Comment: this is table column(content_pdf) binary code value([BLOB - 41.9 KiB])

Comment: $content = $row['content_pdf'];
echo $content;  if i echo this i am getting answer like this                                           %PDF-1.7 3 0 obj <> /Resources 2 0 R /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <>..........

Comment: It looks like your content_pdf field in the DB is exact PDF content - it is not base64 encoded? So use content_pdf field directly without base64_decode and is should work.

Comment: if i have any doubt can i ask you?